# Fotowall for 16.04

Tags: graphics, 16.04

I am looking for Fotowall for 16.04
This [link](http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/xenial/universe/f/fotowall/install/index.html) says it is in the universe repo.

I cannot get it in my repository.
Can someone help me or give information?
Currently I am using pilr via the web.
I need a program to do a collage with pictures.

Comment: Try enabling universe repository, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository

Answer (score 5):

That page you linked to seems to be completely wrong... As pointed out by rancho, fotowall is not in xenial repositories as the developers stopped working on it.

Nontheless, you can still install it as a .deb package built for 16.04 from [this launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/fotowall/0.98~beta+git20150707-1).

First get the dependencies:

```
sudo apt install libqt4-network libqt4-opengl libqt4-svg libqt4-xml libqtcore4 libqtgui4 libqtwebkit4
sudo apt -f install
```

then download the right version for your system - this one is for 64-bit

```
wget launchpadlibrarian.net/211041459/fotowall_0.98~beta+git20150707-1_amd64.deb
```

and this one is for 32-bit (I haven't tested this version as my system is 64-bit)

```
wget launchpadlibrarian.net/211041511/fotowall_0.98~beta+git20150707-1_i386.deb
```

then install (replace `amd64` with `i386` if you got that version - in any use use the exact name):

```
sudo dpkg -i fotowall_0.98~beta+git20150707-1_amd64.deb
```

if any dependency errors pop up, fix them (I've already included all the ones I needed, but you might find more on your system) by installing the packages mentioned: `sudo apt install name-of-package` or with `sudo apt -f install`. When done you can launch by typing

```
fotowall
```

This package works fine in my Xubuntu 16.04

Comment: Thank you.  I will try during my night-time package and get back to you.  I am 64bit Mate, so your instructions should be cut and pasteable.

Comment: yep - I double checked for typos, but comment with any problems & I will support

Comment: Thanks!  It worked and I am up and running with fotowall on 16.04 cutting and pasteing your code blindly and directly.  Not sure if the program can help me make collages easily though..  seems a little weird.   I will have to search how to use it.

Comment: I think the program does not work.  The "save" function does not have the "export" that the youtube video shows and it seems to lock up too.  I guess it has bugs or the dependencies are not all there.

Comment: Oh that sucks. I was enjoying playing with it (it integrates really nicely with gimp if you have it) & no crashes for me, but not being able to export makes it pretty useless. You could try using [ImageMagick](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/27918/23942) but it's CLI based, a bit of a learning curve even with the GraphicsMagick frontend. I also found [this .deb package of 'photocollage'](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/photocollage/1.4.3-1/+build/9795786) for 16.10 which works for me (download & install with `sudo dpkg -i name-of-package.deb`) but is very basic

Comment: I hope that they resume the dev on this app.  I want something like pixlr.  I am thinking of downloading for WinE but it is 100 mb.

Answer (score 0):

The reason may be because fotowall till now is supported only upto Wily Werewolf. See https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fotowall I guess you are using Xenial Xerus